# Is there a binary truth operator in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

What does this expression mean in Vuejs?

```
:class="{ expr1: expr2}"
```

It appears be a truth expression, but is there a binary truth operator in Javascript?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax states that class objects can be binded to class, so there's no stopping to have something like this,  classObject: {
    active: true,
    'text-danger': false,  model:"500"
  } notice the model name which may not be a truth value. Not sure about a clean way of doing this.

Comment: You are correct. You could have a case where you make a mistake that results in a truthy value that will end up with a class you don't really want. But you could return the object from a function that checks to make sure if the object was valid. As in, `:class="makeClassObject"` where `makeClassObject` is a function that returns an object where the properties are classes and the values are booleans. In that function you could validate the booleans as well.

Comment: Also you could use the [strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) to make sure you have a true value: `:class="{expr1: true === expr2}"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the [object syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) for class bindings in Vue. If `expr2` is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, then Vue will add the class, `expr1` to the element.

`:class` is the [shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) for `v-bind:class`.

If that expression was on a `div`, for example,

```
<div :class="{expr1: expr2}"></div>
```

Then, if `expr2` was truthy, the rendered output would be

```
<div class="expr1"></div>
```

**Edit**

Truthy values are often a cause of confusion and errors in javascript. There is however a [strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) that you can use to make sure that you have a `true` value.

```
:class="{expr1: true === expr2}"
```

That will allow you to avoid cases where `expr2` might be *truthy* but not `true`.

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/JJjmKg).

Answer (score 2):

It's a class binding which means the node will get the class expr1 when expr2 is truthy.

Read: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax